# Create parent entity then create children entities with parent ID

Tags: android, android-room, rx-java2

In my code, a `Hero` has many `Power`. To create a `Power` object, I need a `heroId`. In this case, I'm trying to create a hero and then give the hero multiple powers.

Thus, the `HeroDao`:

```
@Dao
public interface HeroDao {
    @Insert
    Single<Long> create(Hero hero);
}
```

And the `PowerDao`:

```
@Dao
public interface PowerDao {
    @Insert
    Completable create(Power power);
}
```

So,

```
Completable createHero(List<Power> powers) {
    return heroDao.create(new Hero())
            .flatMapCompletable(heroId -> Observable.fromIterable(powers)
                    .flatMapCompletable(power -> {
                        power.heroId = heroId;
                        return powerDao.create(power);
                    }))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

But that instead throws an exception:

`io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with.`

That exception also provides a [link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#error-handling) that explains more about that particular error but the details aren't making sense to me since I'm a beginner with limited experience using RxJava.

What's going on?

**UPDATE:**
In my ViewModel, the subscription looks like this:

```
createHero(powers)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(this::success, this::error);
```

Comment: Can you please share the part where you subscribe to your `createHero()` call?

Comment: Also, why not just put list of `Power`s as a property in your `Hero` class, and `HeroDao` will have `insert` and `update` in case new power is assigned? Would make more sense to me.

Comment: My bad. I've updated the question with how I'm subscribing in the ViewModel. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `createHero()` to log errors:

```
Completable createHero(List<Power> powers) {
    return heroDao.create(new Hero())
            // add explicit error log
            .doOnError(e -> Log.e("ERROR", "insert hero error", e))
            .flatMapCompletable(heroId -> Observable.fromIterable(powers)
                    .flatMapCompletable(power -> {
                        power.setHeroId(heroId);
                        return create(power)
                                .doOnError(e -> Log.e("ERROR", "insert power error", e))
                    }))
}
```

You should now see what error is really thrown.

Comment: In any case, all my code was fine, it was the `.doOnError()` checks that I was missing to really get to the root of the problem. It turned out my `Hero` objects were missing some required fields before insertion into the database. Myyy baddd!